# Nikon D3100 vs Canon EOS 600D

Tags: dslr, canon, nikon

Which one is better? Please reply if you have used and seen images taken by both DSLR!

Comment: What do you mean by better?  Please clarify to make the question more objective.

Answer (score 1):

http://snapsort.com/compare/Canon-600d-vs-Nikon_D3100

only this will help you=) because you ask to compare EVERYTHING about them, too abstract question. better go that page and see for your self.